# scalar valued function in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

```
def fnction(y):
df=spark.sql(""" select * from tbl where tbl.col2={y}
""")
return df.col1


df1=spark.sql(""" select fnction(col1) from tbl2
""")
```

I'm getting error in this approach. what is the correct way to call a function from a dataframe passing one column and filter another dataframe inside function using passed column

Comment: Please explain more.